# Is it safe to use several keys in Vigenere cipher method to encrypt?

Tags: encryption, vigenere

I am just curious about whether it is safe or not to use this encryptiong method showed below.
Assume we have a list of keys to be used in the encrypt process, for example, ['apple','coco','piano']. For each key in the list, we use this key and the Vigenere cipher method to encrypt the text. So in this example here, we will first use 'apple' to encrypt the target text, then use 'coco' to encrypt again, finally use 'piano' to encrypt.
So, is it safe to use this kind of method? Thanks.

Comment: What is safe primarily depends on the length of the key. These keys are far too short to be useful. Basically, choose a key which is at least as long as the ciphertext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the Vigenere cipher severel times with different keys, a (common) key can be constructed that will give the same result.

When encrypting with Vigenere you would repeate the key to match the data you want to encrypt. If you want to encrypt the text `the secret message is we attack a dawn` with the key `apple` you would set it up like this:

```
Text:       the secret message is we attack a dawn
Key:        appleappleappleappleappleappleappleapp
            --------------------------------------
Encrypted:  uxu xfshqy cuexbwu nt mq bjjmhl q ibmd
```

If you then were to encrypt that again with `coco` you would have:

```
Text:       uxu xfshqy cuexbwu nt mq bjjmhl q ibmd
Key:        cococococococococococococococococococo
            --------------------------------------
Encrypted:  xmx auvwtn rxtaqzj cw pf qmypwo t lqps
```

Also notice how `coco` is actually a *"weak"* key that give the same result at just `co` ! Anyway .. in this case a combined key of `apple` & `coco` is `desahpseot` so you have:

```
Text:       the secret message is we attack a dawn
Key:        desahpseotdesahpseotdesahpseotdesahpse
            --------------------------------------
Encrypted:  xmx auvwtn rxtaqzj cw pf qmypwo t lqps
```

Notice how the key `desahpseot` is just combined like this:

```
key 1:        appleapple
key 2:        cococococo
              ----------
Combined key: desahpseot
```

Answer (score 0):

Which "safe"? It is safe as in not dangerous, as in it won't break anything. It is not particularly safe as in secure, since you can find a key that is the combination of these three keys (though it likely won't be an English word). There are encryption schemes which get more secure when you repeat them; Vigenere is not one of them.